# select if only one option available in dropdown & disable

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a jquery dropdown. Usually there are multiple options in my drop down to select from but for some products there is only one option I want the script to be able to select the value if only one option is there and disable the dropdown. Existing code is:

```
RonisCatalog.selectSwatches = function(element, options){
if (jQuery('body .swatches-container').size()==0)
    return ;

else    
var selectOptions = jQuery(element).find('option'),
    selectOptionsValues = {};
var selectLabel = '';
jQuery.each(selectOptions,function(idx,selectOption){
    if (jQuery(selectOption).val()=='')
        selectLabel = jQuery(selectOption).html();
    selectOptionsValues[jQuery(selectOption).val()] = jQuery(selectOption).val();
});
jQuery('body .swatches-container .swatch-type-id-'+element.attributeId).parents('.swatch-list-continer').children('.swatch-list-label').html('<label id="attribute'+element.attributeId+'_label" >Select '+selectLabel+'</label>');
jQuery('body .swatches-container .swatch-type-id-'+element.attributeId+' .swatch-option').addClass('swatch-disabled').removeClass('swatch-active');

jQuery.each(options,function(idx,option){
    if (typeof selectOptionsValues[option.id] != 'undefined')
        jQuery('body .swatches-container .swatch-type-id-'+element.attributeId+' .swatch-option-id-'+option.id).removeClass('swatch-disabled');
});
};
```

I want to use this option in between:

```
else if (jQuery('body .swatches-container').size()==1) {


}
```

and functionality as described above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
else if ($jQuery('body .swatches-container').size() == 1) {
    $jQuery('body .swatches-container').val('0').attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, I added this piece of code. It doesn't select the first option but it disables the swatches container values so that you cannot select the given value.